# SQL Server clear memory

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to clear RAM memory from data that SQL Server fill in?

Is there any procedure or option which can do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: SQL server release memmory after service restart, but if I won't need to restart, how can I clear memmory? I don't know if it is even possible, but I am curious whether SQL Server cover that topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

to [remove all data pages from memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx).  It's useful to test server performance: a query performs differently if the data pages it needs are not cached.

Answer (score 2):

You don't release memory. If you want it to use less memory, then add the restriction in server settings.

If you did release the memory, it would slow down your queries as everything would have to be read from disk again.

Comment: Slowing down of queries may be of secondary importance to what the OP is trying to achieve.