# SQL Server - free disk space after dropping index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

After creating a nonclustered index on a SQL Server table, it leads to disk space used increase. Even after we dropped the index, the difference of disk space in use used didn't change.

Before creating the nonclustered index, total size on disk was 8.5GB:

[image]

After creating the nonclustered index, the total size on disk increased to 8.99GB:

[image]

Any idea how to free disk space used by dropped index?

Comment: Unless you've run out, SQL Server is going to keep the memory forever (or until a reboot or you clear *all* memory). This is why there is a min/max memory setting. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646195/sql-server-clear-memory

Comment: Server has already been rebooted but no change. Memory is still being used by SQL Server

Comment: Please update the post with your minimum and maximum memory settings.

Comment: I m not having issues with RAM Memory , but sizes of Data files on disk

Comment: Ok... so the physical files are not the same thing as memory. And shrinking the database files is generally considered not a good idea. Check here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17277/when-is-it-ok-to-shrink-a-database

Comment: I updated your question and replaced the word Memory with Disk Space as that is what you are ask about. Disk space and Memory are *not* interchangeable terms.

Comment: Clearly a database management/administration question. VTC as off-topic; belongs on DBA SE site.